# Phantom MySQL rows?

Tags: mysql

When I do:

```
select count(1) from tbl_name;
```

it shows 299999 rows (that's also what I see when I scroll to the last row), but inside phpmyadmin it shows 309675 total rows).

What could be causing this?

Table is

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

[image]

The table was populated with 299999 queries like below

```
INSERT INTO keyword_traffic1 (ID, keyword) VALUES ("", "'.$string.'");
```

Comment: What inserts into that table?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I've updated the question with the sample insert query used to populate it